# How can I flip or mirror the entire screen display (have root)

Tags: root-access, settings, screen, external-display

I have a rooted Android device and I want to see everything that is on the screen "reversed" or "flipped horizontally" basically so that if you viewed the screen in a mirror it would look correct (text legible as normal) but if you view it directly without the mirror it would look backwords (text running the wrong direction and flipped).

I found [this page](http://www.androidtablets.net/threads/screen-backwards-or-mirroring.45271/) with people talking about a tablet that was malfunctioning in the manner that I am hoping to achieve, but there wasn't much info that would help me do this on purpose.

I'm hopping for some low level setting or flag somewhere on the system that I can change with root that will flip the whole display for me.

Comment: Can you tell us why do you want this? I mean, there may be a higher goal which you want to achieve through this , but can also be achieved another way.

Comment: I have a specialized screen but it's control board in it is currently a bit wonky atm and it mirrors the content just as I described. My intent is to mirror it again in the Android device that I am am driving content with so that it offsets the screen and displays normally. Obviously not ideal, but this would make it easier to use this screen while we wait for the fix to the control board.